# View to get _changes with specific values

Tags: couchdb

I can get the latest changed document by using:

```
localhost:5984/_changes
```

and then use the documentID's returned and obtain the document using

```
localhost:5984/documentID
```

I was wondering if I can combine them into a view - the view would execute _changes, get the document with the specific documentIDs and return those

Answer (score 6):

Changes queries can also include the entire document if you add a `?include_docs=true` parameter.

To see only some documents instead of all of them, you can use filter functions: http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/notifications.html#filters

When calling a filtered _changes feed, you can also provide parameters, i.e.

```
 localhost:5984/db/_changes?include_docs=true&filter=foo/docs&id=docid
```

Using as filter:

```
function(doc, req)
{
  if(doc._id == req.query.id) {
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

This will return only those documents matching the filter, including the document bodies.

Comment: actually, I wanted something different - right now _changes gets me a list of IDs of documents that have been updated, I want other document attributes i.e. if my doc has fields doc.firstname and doc.lastname, I want _changes or a view/filter to return me the changed doc.lastname, doc.firstname pair, and not doc._id

Comment: Then use update handlers, that set a special flag on this specific change and filter for the flag at _changes.

Comment: What you want is possible with `_changes` too. I will update this answer slightly to show how.

Comment: Filtering for a document id is not a real-world use case (you could just query for the doc directly), however the example is nice and clear.